Multi Pod Cloud Environment Spring Boot application change log level at runtime
I have an application used spring boot + log4j2 running on openshift more than 2 pods.
However, our logging configuration changing after sprint boot initalized i mean , reconfigure. So, i do not use xml configuration. ( Btw i could not use xml based configuration)
With using actuator/logger endpoint, by calling the endpoint , ocp choose 1 pod to process the call.
is there any solution to call all pods?
Or any feature for actuator to get information all pods like using rabbitmq (i mean  like cloud config)
I hope you can help me.

I haven't researched, but I think there is probably some sort of observability platform that can handle this. SO is for specific issues more then general questions.

Cant find a solution. So, i know this is a question.but some solutions may ingress policy can be written? Or log4j2 hybrit confuguration etc. Someone who faced the problem could share the solution. Am i right?

Answer to this question, one of the solutions is to use spring cloud bus trigger custom events
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/spring-cloud-bus/custom-events.html
